# Apache not loading homepage

Tags: linux, web-server, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

My site `www.domainname.com` loads apache2 'It works' page instead of the expected home page of moode which is located at `/var/www/html/moodle`. There is an index file `index.php` inside moodle directory but it is not taken by default. If I go to `www.domainname.com/moodle` the site homepage comes. The configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.conf` is enabled. How to solve this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.domainname.com
    ServerAlias domainname.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
    DirectoryIndex "index.php"
    # <Directory /var/www/html/>
    #       AllowOverride All
    # </Directory>  

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domainname.com
 RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by changing the line

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php
```

in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`.

**Source :**
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Answer (score 0):

• Did you restart Apache2 after changing the config files / enabling sites? That's the fault I do most times 
• Are there other enabled sites maybe causing a conflict? Try to temporarily disable them.